# Wireframing and copywriting, what comes first?

Tags: client-relations, designers, wireframing

I feel like this is a chicken-vs-egg problem.

Can you assume the client will have all the copy ready by the time you start the wireframe? Or does the client need to see the wireframe first so he/she can come up with the copywriting that fits the wireframe?

Comment: No, don't assume anything. Anyway you can just use some lorem ipsum place holder text if your client doesn't have the copy ready yet.

Comment: Every client can be different. You should be prepared either way.

Comment: No. Why would you think that? How could it matter?

How could Billy Kerr's lorem ipsum not work, unless this was about specific content and meaning… which seems outside the scope of the Question?

'Wireframing' happens to be a term I've never before your Post met, in more than 30 years of writing, designing and producing magazines and newspapers… So what?

Could your seeing this as a chicken-vs-egg problem say more about your experience than anything else?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm looking for experiences of other web developers, there's a few methods that are used, 1) Ask the client for all copywriting in advance, 2) As a web designer, write out the titles, use lorem ipsum for all the rest 3) Write out a draft copy titles + content 4) use lorem ipsum for everything - which might cause issues if the copywriting from the client is different in size. Since you've never heard of the term Wireframing, I'm sure this discussion doesn't concern you.

Comment: @MiguelStevens Thanks and none of that matters, if you don't work on assumptions.

Whether the client has all the copy ready or needs to see your design first is about simple logic and logistics, not anything technical. Who doubts that please, say why!

When were graphic design in general or copywriting in particular subsumed into 'wireframing' except by your tutor? If you insist, you're welcome to explain… otherwise, why not look at the real meaning of what you Posted?

When you do that, do you see no difference in 'copy' and 'copywriting' and, come to that, 'writing copy'?

Answer (score 4):

No, you should not assume that.

Anything can happen basically, the client can delay the content, they can delay the feedback, they can change your deadlines, they can add more content outside your perfect lorem ipsum wireframe, they can ask if you're available on sunday.

Delivering work is a process and you need to be prepared for that.

---

*Regarding your other comment*

If you are under salary, I guess you will need to take it for what it is.

As a freelancer, you can have some rules (especially good with new clients):

- avoid vague jobs with incomplete content/briefing and pressing deadlines
- charge hourly, so you earn more if it takes longer (many times it will take longer)
- avoid flat rates
- never create content, unless you charge for that aswell

If a client comes to us for design work, and they don't have the copy ready, we will kindly ask them to come back when the copy is ready. If they don't understand what this means (aka time & money), we will move on to the next client. Normally this happens with small, unexperienced clients, which we avoid anyway. You should be looking for the big clients, that have teams in place and budgets, and the copy is a non-issue with those clients.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the project, on the client, etc.

I've worked in some (very few) website projects where the copy was ready before the wireframes, because it was a small website and the client already knew what they wanted to communicate with it.

Most of the time (especially larger projects) you will have no copy, sometimes some from a few sections once a rough structure is defined. But as Lucian mentions in his answer, many variables can change over time, sometimes the scope of the project change and sections of the project can be axed / added / modified.

Therefore you should not assume anything when starting a design project.

Comment: So what do you do when no copy is available? Use lorem ipsum in the wireframes? Or do you type out some copy yourself?

Comment: @MiguelStevens I wouldn't write copy for a client's project unless agreed in the scope of the project - in which case I'd hire a copywriter, since writing copy is not one of my skills.

Answer (score 1):

What is the advantage of a website, if you do not have flexibility?

A modern communication project is not made of solid, stiff blocks, it is an intertwined process, and flexibility to change things, mold them and adapt them is a key element.

Probably **the dichotomy is not between "content and form"** probably is between having defined objectives or not, between defining a structure or not.

Remember that a communication process has different elements besides the message. It starts "obviously" with the emitter, but the real construction of the message starts with the receiver, defining who he is, what he needs to know, what is interested in knowing, how we should inform it, and how to catch the attention, etc.

**Structure**. That is a keyword. A structure should be reflected in both, plain text with clear sections, and wireframe with clear sections.

Content and form shape each other. In electronic mediums, we have more versatility compared to when you had a defined area and space in a paper. But still, the content is defined by the space, the visual hierarchy, and the visual flux is defined by the content of the message.

And both are defined by some basic structure layouts that must be defined.

---

Imho that answers your questions, but let me clarify a bit more.

> Can you assume the client will have all the copy ready by the time you start the wireframe?

You can not assume anything. That is why an interview is important, some meetings.

That depends if you are only working as a freelancer (a designer), if you are part of a team, if you integrate early in a project or late; if it is a redesign; if it is a new project; if the client has the resources; if he needs advice or guidance on how to proceed. I could go on and on...

> Or does the client need to see the wireframe first so he/she can come up with the copywriting that fits the wireframe?

That would be a bit egocentric. You can not present an almighty wireframe that defines reality. As I said, the wireframe responds to many things defined by the structure.

Sometimes will give ideas on what elements you currently do not have. You need a hero image; if you do not have one, you need to ask for it. If the length of the written content is not long enough or is too long, you (the team) need to adapt it.

Flexibility, feedback, teamwork.

---

And as some others have commented about fees, yes you need to define stages of the project, some with specific fees, and define what you do and what you do not do. But that is a whole other topic.

Comment: I agree about the structure, the discovery meeting is important to learn who the client's client is, en what the goal of the website is. Maybe it's a good idea to define a "Content map", a Sitemap that also includes sections for each page, the client then knows what content goes where on the page, from that we can build the wireframe which can include more real copy.